# How do I send post data with jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, post

I'm trying to create a button that'll send post data elsewhere, is there anyway I can do this with JavaScript or Ajax/jQuery?

If there's any information I'm leaving out, please tell me.

Comment: Read about jQuery .post method: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Ans yes...many ways to do it

Comment: Alright, thanks guys.  I knew this'd get downvoted, but whatever.

Comment: Add some codes which you have tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: @AndreiSfat Possibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you to do what you are looking for.

[Send Post request using jQuery.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Did you even Google this....

Ajax/jQuery will do the work....

Check it yourself and show some work over here.

Comment: Yes, I did actually, why else would I come here if I didn't search Google first?